# Не работает псевдоэлемент ::after

Tags: html, css

Когда поле валидное должен появляться + но он не появляется

```css
.popup-subscribe__box {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-subscribe__label {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #171717;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.popup-subscribe__input {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F1F4F8;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 24px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #070033;
}

.popup-subscribe__input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:hover {
  border: 1px solid #838099;
}
.popup-subscribe__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #800080;
  outline: none;
}
.popup-subscribe__input:valid {
  border: 1px solid #1749B3;
}

.popup-subscribe__box::after {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 17px;
    transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
    transform: scale(0);
    background-color: #1ED760;
}
.popup-subscribe__input:valid.popup-subscribe__box-name::after {
    transform: scale(1);
}}
```

```html
<div class="popup-subscribe__box popup-subscribe__box-name">
  <label class="popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-subscribe__name">Enter your name</label>
  <input class="popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-subscribe__name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Anastasiia" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не сможете `.popup-subscribe__input:valid.popup-subscribe__box-name` сделать так, это невозможно. Вы никак не обратитесь к `popup-subscribe__box-name` в данном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.popup-subscribe__box {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-subscribe__label {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #171717;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.popup-subscribe__input {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F1F4F8;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 24px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #070033;
}

.popup-subscribe__input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:hover {border: 1px solid gray;}
.popup-subscribe__input:focus {border: 1px solid violet;}
.popup-subscribe__input:valid {border: 1px solid green;}

.popup-subscribe__label::after {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 17px;
    transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
    transform: scale(0);
    background-color: #1ED760;
}
.popup-subscribe__input:valid:not(:focus) + .popup-subscribe__label:after {transform: scale(1);}
/* можно конечно заменить + на ~,  в теории это должно
позволить обратно поменять местами input и label, но
это в теории... */
```

```html
<div class="popup-subscribe__box popup-subscribe__box-name">
  <input class="popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-subscribe__name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Anastasiia" required>
  <label class="popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-subscribe__name">Enter your name</label>
</div>
```